# HTML Editor in Flex

Tags: html, apache-flex, wysiwyg

Anyone knows a good (wysiwyg) HTML editor in Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you're going to find is to use the iFrame trick that pops up an iFrame with an HTML Editor in it. You can Google IFrame Flex to find more info.  I believe that Drumbeat Insight has an HTML Component that helps make this easier.

But, as far as an HTML Editor inside of Flex, you're going to be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Flextras, you are just confirming what I've found. Why you think nobody has created one? many, many Flex app out there and I'm sure mane of them need to interact with formated content.

Comment: We've considered it, but I anticipate the level of work to be significant >1 year.  Did you just want an HTML Editor in Flex?  Or do you want to be able to display the results too?

Comment: I know what you mean, just edit the code would be easy, but I'm looking for a WYSIWYG! tks!

Comment: I don't believe editing the HTML would be easy.  But, that said, an  HTML Renderer and an WYSIWYG HTML Editor would be two very different beasts; although possibly could be based off the same code base.

Answer (score 0):

I just found nice wysiwyg html editor for FLEX on
http://www.atomwrite.com/